# Expand state array length based on user input

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to expand a state.array based on a user input length. However each button press only expands the array by 1 (aka the for loop is not iterating entirely). Does someone know why this is?

In this case x would be the user input length, I have assigned it a constant value for simplicity's sake.

```
class DisplaySort extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: [],
     };
    this.generateArray = this.generateArray.bind(this);
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.generateArray}>Generate Array</button>
     </div>
    );
  }

  generateArray(e) {
    let x = 15;
    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      this.setState({ array: [...this.state.array, " "] });
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that requires you to _expand_ your array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each time you call `this.setState` inside the loop, the prev `setState` haven't populated yet cause the async behavior `setState` have (it doesn't act immediately but tells the component it should run again with a new state). Therefore using `setState` in a loop isn't a predictable code and should've something like

```
generateArray(e) {
    let x = 15;
    this.setState({ array: [...this.state.array, ...Array(x).fill(' ')] });
    }
```

where I call `setState` only once

or still with loop but only one `setState`

```
generateArray(e) {
    let x = 15;
    let array = [...this.state.array]
    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      array = [...array, ' ']
    }
    this.setState({ array });
   }
```